# Site for commonly used methods for GUI in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I'm a beginner trying to explore Visual Studio Community 2015 & its windows form application (without any book and teacher, only Google). Just now, I had been trying to figure out how to use the 'ComboBox' controls. At first, I thought I had to use

`if (comboBox1.Items.Text = "Book")`
`Do something`

But after watching several videos, it's actually

`if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)` `Do something`

Is there any site where commonly used methods & how it's being used for all the GUI?

Edit: I knew some basic coding like variables, class, exception etc. I want a site or book where it shows how the 'common controls' are being used whenever an event is happening.

Comment: You can try the following https://www.amazon.com/dp/0672328917

Comment: I took a glimpse and it's not what I'm looking for. See my edit statements

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to learn windows programming

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorials/c-sharp/gui-windows/1

Hope this helps!!